# How to click the element from span and link text?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Here is the code. Its a send message Button. I tried many ways it's not working. Please help me.

```
<a href="#" class="dt-btn dt-btn-m dt-btn-submit" rel="nofollow" xpath="1"><span>Send message</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Can you modify the Html?

Comment: Btw, following the lead, that this is no code-providing platform, you should provide your best not-working attempt.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element you can use either of the following solutions:

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.dt-btn.dt-btn-m.dt-btn-submit[rel='nofollow']>span")).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='dt-btn dt-btn-m dt-btn-submit']/span[text()='Send message']")).click();
  ```

Comment: @shahadathossain What exactly isn't working? What error do you see? Update the question with your current code trials and error stack trace.